# regex in python not working - works in pythex but not in python 3.6

Tags: python, regex

This regex works in pythex, but not in python 3.6.  I am not sure why:

[Pythex link (click)](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3FP%3Cpun1%3E%5Cd%7B3%7D)%5Cs%2B(%3FP%3Cpun2%3E%5Cd%7B6%7D)(%5Cs%2B(%3FP%3Cpun3%3E%5B01oO%5D)(%5Cs%2B(%3FP%3Cpun4%3E%5Cd%7B4%7D))%3F)%3F%5Cs.*%5Cs(%3FP%3Camt%3E%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%5Cd)%5Cs&test_string=105297%20%09003%20%09002394%20%09o%20%090000%20%0920891%20%090.00%20%091%20%09%0A105297%20003%20%20002394%20%20o%20%200000%20%2020891%20%200.00%20%201%0A105297%20%20003%20%20002394%20%20o%20%200000%20%2020891%20%200.00%20%201%0A105297%20%20003%20%20002394%20%20o%20%200000%20%2020891%20%200.00%20%201%0A%0A(%3FP%3Cpun1%3E%5Cd%7B3%7D)%5Cs%2B(%3FP%3Cpun2%3E%5Cd%7B6%7D)(%5Cs%2B(%3FP%3Cpun3%3E%5B01oO%5D)(%5Cs%2B(%3FP%3Cpun4%3E%5Cd%7B4%7D))%3F)%3F%5Cs.*%5Cs(%3FP%3Camt%3E%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%5Cd)%5Cs%0A(%3FP%3Cpun1%3E%5Cd%7B3%7D)%5Cs%2B(%3FP%3Cpun2%3E%5Cd%7B6%7D)(%5Cs%2B(%3FP%3Cpun3%3E%5B01oO%5D)(%5Cs%2B(%3FP%3Cpun4%3E%5Cd%7B4%7D))%3F)%3F%5Cs.*%5Cs(%3FP%3Camt%3E%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%5Cd)%5Cs&ignorecase=1&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Code in python:

```
import re
test = '105297  003  002394  o  0000  20891  0.00  1'
pattern = r"(?P<pun1>\d{3})\s+(?P<pun2>\d{6})(\s+(?P<pun3>[01oO])(\s+(?P<pun4>\d{4}))?)?\s.*\s(?P<amt>\d+\.\d\d)\s"
match = re.match(pattern, test, re.IGNORECASE)
match is None
True
```

I haven't been able to figure out why it works in pythex but not in python interpreter.

Comment: What does it suppose to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for `re.search()` not `re.match()`. The latter only matches at the start of the string (implies an anchor `^`, that is):

```
match = re.search(pattern, test, re.IGNORECASE)
#            ^^^
if match:
    # change the world here
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/z2uz5E/2).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problems comes from calling `re.match` instead of [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.search). The `re.search` function tries to find the regex in the given string, while `re.match` requires the regex to match at the beginning of the string.

Change this:

```
match = re.match(pattern, test, re.IGNORECASE)
```

to this:

```
match = re.search(pattern, test, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that match() is used for matching the beginning of a string, not anywehere.
from python docs: ([Python docs for match()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match))

"If zero or more characters at the **beginning** of string match this regular expression, return a corresponding match object."

You should use search() instead:
"If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use search() instead."

[see also search() vs. match()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

this part:

```
match = re.match(pattern, test, re.IGNORECASE)
```

has to be:

```
match = re.search(pattern, test, re.IGNORECASE)
```